# Is Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC replaced by Keno UI for MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I found a sample project that are built on Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC + MVC3. I tried to download Is Telerik Extensions, but could not find it at anywhere. It seems it is for MVC3, after that, it is Kendo UI MVC for MVC4+. So, Is Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC replaced by Keno UI for MVC?

If yes, does it mean we can always rewrite this sample project using Kendo UI MVC? But it seems some do not exist in Kendo anymore, i.e. GridModel, TreeViewItem, ... is there a document to explain this?

Thanks

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation. The MVC wrappers are dll's based on the version of MVC you are using and must be purchased. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/introduction

Answer (score 0):

You cannot direct download the Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC + MVC3. You need to get them via NuGet.

For that,

1. Fist, open NuGet package manager console in visual studio.
2. Type the following in console.

Install-Package TelerikMvcExtensions.

3. Then you will get all Telerik extensions.